# Inconsistent AST received by Attached Macro

Tags: swift, macros

Consider the following:

```swift
struct Person { 
    @MyPeerMacro var name = "John Doe"
}
```

here, the `MyPeerMacro` will receive the following AST: *(1)*

```swift
VariableDeclSyntax
├─attributes: AttributeListSyntax
│ ╰─[0]: AttributeSyntax
│   ├─atSign: atSign
│   ╰─attributeName: IdentifierTypeSyntax
│     ╰─name: identifier("MyPeerMacro")  // << MyPeerMacro lists itself as an attribute
├─modifiers: DeclModifierListSyntax
├─bindingSpecifier: keyword(SwiftSyntax.Keyword.var)
╰─bindings: PatternBindingListSyntax
```

However, if the struct was like this instead: *(2)*

```swift
@ApplyMyPeerMacroToAllDeclarations struct Person { 
    var name = "John Doe"
}
```

which **expands** to:
*(`@MyPeerMacro` added automatically by `@ApplyMyPeerMacroToAllDeclarations`)*

```swift
struct Person { 
    @MyPeerMacro var name = "John Doe"
}
```

would such a struct *not* list `MyPeerMacro` in the list of attributes? eg: *(3)*

```swift
VariableDeclSyntax
├─attributes: AttributeListSyntax  // << doesn't list MyPeerMacro here
├─modifiers: DeclModifierListSyntax
├─bindingSpecifier: keyword(SwiftSyntax.Keyword.var)
╰─bindings: PatternBindingListSyntax
```

The reason why I'm asking this is because the implementation of `ObservationTracked` in the Swift Library is as follows:
*Some code omitted for clarity*

```swift
extension ObservationTrackedMacro: PeerMacro {
    public static func expansion(of node: AttributeSyntax,
                                 providingPeersOf declaration: some DeclSyntaxProtocol,
                                 in context: some MacroExpansionContext)
    throws -> [DeclSyntax] {
        // Checks if the declaration is a stored property that is valid for observation...
        
        if property.hasMacroApplication(ObservableMacro.ignoredMacroName) ||
            property.hasMacroApplication(ObservableMacro.trackedMacroName) {  // << Here is the code that interested me
            return []
        }
        
        // Adds a property prefixed with an underscore and marked with @ObservationIgnored...
    }
}
```

If you notice the code marked with `// <<`, it checks if the variable declaration contains an attribute named "ObservationTracked" (this is what `ObservableMacro.trackedMacroName` evaluates to), and if it does, it *does not* add anything.

This is very strange because I'm under the impression that any declaration marked with `@ObservationTracked` will also contain `.identifier("ObservationTracked")` in its list of attributes (see `MyPeerMacro` example above labelled (1), it lists itself) and thus, that expression would always evaluate to `true`. This is reinforced by the fact that if I manually type `@ObsevationTracked` on a property, it doesn't add anything, indicating that that expression is probably evaluating to `true` as it contains itself in the list of attributes.

The only way this code will make sense if any attributes added automatically by a Member Attribute Macro do not contain themselves in the list of attributes on the declaration (Since `@Observable` automatically adds `@ObservationTracked` on stored property declarations). That's the only way for that expression to evaluate to `false`.

When I tested this myself, I got mixed results. When I use Unit Tests, the AST **always** lists the macro like in (1), however, when I use:

```
public struct MyPeerMacro: PeerMacro {
    public static func expansion(of node: AttributeSyntax,
                                 providingPeersOf declaration: some DeclSyntaxProtocol,
                                 in context: some MacroExpansionContext)
    throws -> [DeclSyntax] {
        let variableDecl = declaration.cast(VariableDeclSyntax.self)
        return ["\(raw: variableDecl.debugDescription)"]
    }
}

public struct ApplyMyPeerMacroToAllDeclarationsMacro: MemberAttributeMacro {
    public static func expansion(of node: AttributeSyntax, 
                                 attachedTo declaration: some DeclGroupSyntax,
                                 providingAttributesFor member: some DeclSyntaxProtocol,
                                 in context: some MacroExpansionContext) throws -> [AttributeSyntax] {
        return ["@MyPeerMacro"]
    }
}
```

And then use Xcode to expand a struct like in (2), the output I get is **always** (3).

Im utterly confused by all this because I would expect to receive the same AST regardless of how the attached macro was applied (whether manually or automatically by another macro). Can someone shed some light as to why this is happening, is it a bug? Also, this makes me wonder if `@MyPeerMacro` was added to a declaration by another Peer Macro, what would be the behaviour? Would we get an AST like (1) or like (3)?